# I want to make an online recruitment website

Tags: php

I want to make an online recruitment system(web) for my project in school. What are the language I need to learn except PHP. Thanks for the answer guys.

Answer (score 1):

Not very proper question, you might find the answer by googling.

Anyway, You might need so far:

**HTML**: It will be like the skeleton of your page.

**CSS**: Basic knowledge would be a plus for understanding how to make it pretty.

**MySQL**: Unless you want a static page, you would need  DB in order to save the data itself. Useful for manage cookies, sessions, users, etc.

My advice - Download some HTML free template and use it as base. Integrate it with PHP for DB connection and usage.